# Track listings to time tables

Tags: code-golf, string, date

### Introduction

Don't you hate it when someone uploads an album you like to YouTube, but the description only contains a **track listing**? Like this:

```
1. Everything in Its Right Place - 4:11
2. Kid A - 4:44
3. The National Anthem - 5:50
4. How to Disappear Completely - 5:55
5. Treefingers - 3:42
6. Optimistic - 5:16
7. In Limbo - 3:31
8. Idioteque - 5:09
9. Morning Bell - 4:29
10. Motion Picture Soundtrack - 6:59
```

Now you don't know when *Morning Bell* starts unless you sum a bunch of times in your head! Usually, some good soul will come by and leave a handy **time table** in the (dreaded) comments section, which looks something like this:

```
(0:00:00) Everything in Its Right Place
(0:04:11) Kid A
(0:08:55) The National Anthem
(0:14:45) How to Disappear Completely
(0:20:40) Treefingers
(0:24:22) Optimistic
(0:29:38) In Limbo
(0:33:09) Idioteque
(0:38:18) Morning Bell
(0:42:47) Motion Picture Soundtrack
```

### Specification

- Your task is to write a program or function that takes a track listing as input and a time table as output.

  - You may choose to read input from STDIN, or an argument string, or an argument list of lines. Similarly, you may choose to print output to STDOUT, or return a string, or return a list of lines. Failing these, do whatever makes sense for your language.
- You may assume each input line has the format `(\d+)\. [A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,100} - (\d+):(\d\d)`. For the regex-impaired, this essentially means you can assume each line is well-formatted (as above) and **song titles consist only of alphanumeric ASCII characters and spaces**, and are no longer than 100 bytes long.
- A track's length is always at least `0:01` and no more than `59:59`.
- The track numbers are increasing order, starting from `1`, and counting up to no more than `99`.
- The total length of an album is no more than `9:59:59`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code (in bytes) wins.

### Test case

Your program should correctly perform the conversion presented in the introduction (Radiohead's *Kid A*). Here is a bigger test case (Sufjan Stevens' *Illinois*<sup>1</sup>) with long strings your program should also work on:

```
1. Concerning the UFO Sighting Near Highland Illinois - 2:08
2. The Black Hawk War - 2:14
3. Come On Feel the Illinoise - 6:45
4. John Wayne Gacy Jr - 3:19
5. Jacksonville - 5:24
6. A Short Reprise for Mary Todd Who Went Insane but for Very Good Reasons - 0:47
7. Decatur or Round of Applause for Your Stepmother - 3:03
8. One Last Whoo Hoo for the Pullman - 0:06
9. Chicago - 6:04
10. Casimir Pulaski Day - 5:53
11. To the Workers of the Rock River Valley Region - 1:40
12. The Man of Metropolis Steals Our Hearts - 6:17
13. Prairie Fire That Wanders About - 2:11
14. A Conjunction of Drones Simulating the Way - 0:19
15. The Predatory Wasp of the Palisades Is Out to Get Us - 5:23
16. They Are Night Zombies They Are Neighbors They Have Come Back from the Dead Ahhhh - 5:09
17. Lets Hear That String Part Again Because I Dont Think They Heard It All the Way Out in Bushnell - 0:40
18. In This Temple as in the Hearts of Man for Whom He Saved the Earth - 0:35
19. The Seers Tower - 3:53
20. The Tallest Man the Broadest Shoulders - 7:02
21. Riffs and Variations on a Single Note - 0:46
22. Out of Egypt into the Great Laugh of Mankind and I Shake the Dirt from My Sandals as I Run - 4:21
```

The correct output is:

```
(0:00:00) Concerning the UFO Sighting Near Highland Illinois
(0:02:08) The Black Hawk War
(0:04:22) Come On Feel the Illinoise
(0:11:07) John Wayne Gacy Jr
(0:14:26) Jacksonville
(0:19:50) A Short Reprise for Mary Todd Who Went Insane but for Very Good Reasons
(0:20:37) Decatur or Round of Applause for Your Stepmother
(0:23:40) One Last Whoo Hoo for the Pullman
(0:23:46) Chicago
(0:29:50) Casimir Pulaski Day
(0:35:43) To the Workers of the Rock River Valley Region
(0:37:23) The Man of Metropolis Steals Our Hearts
(0:43:40) Prairie Fire That Wanders About
(0:45:51) A Conjunction of Drones Simulating the Way
(0:46:10) The Predatory Wasp of the Palisades Is Out to Get Us
(0:51:33) They Are Night Zombies They Are Neighbors They Have Come Back from the Dead Ahhhh
(0:56:42) Lets Hear That String Part Again Because I Dont Think They Heard It All the Way Out in Bushnell
(0:57:22) In This Temple as in the Hearts of Man for Whom He Saved the Earth
(0:57:57) The Seers Tower
(1:01:50) The Tallest Man the Broadest Shoulders
(1:08:52) Riffs and Variations on a Single Note
(1:09:38) Out of Egypt into the Great Laugh of Mankind and I Shake the Dirt from My Sandals as I Run
```

### Leaderboard

For your score to appear on the board, it should be in this format:

```
# Language, Bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=58231,OVERRIDE_USER=3852;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

<sup>1. Apologies to Sufjan, whose amazing track names I had to mangle a bit in order to make them fit the simple format this problem is limited to.</sup>

Comment: May the output contain trailing spaces?

Comment: Radiohead and Sufjan Stevens? Meh :-P

Comment: Nope; the format for each line is `(h:mm:ss) Track Name`, followed immediately by a newline.

Comment: @LuisMendo Feel free to demonstrate your superior music tastes in your answer...?

Comment: Hahaha. That's a good additional motivation to answer. BTW I liked the challenge and I've upvoted it

Comment: Is it disallowed to use `(hh:mm:ss)`, for instance `(01:01:22)`?

Comment: Yes, that's disallowed. It must be `(h:mm:ss)` exactly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## CJam, <s>60</s> <s>57</s> 55 bytes

*Thanks to Sp3000 for saving 2 bytes.*

```
qN/{T60bZ0e["(%d:%02d:%02d) "e%\S/1>)':/60bT+:T;W<S*N}/
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7BT60bZ0e%5B%22(%25d%3A%2502d%3A%2502d)%20%22e%25%5CS%2F1%3E)'%3A%2F60bT%2B%3AT%3BW%3CS*N%7D%2F&input=1.%20Dash%20and%20Blast%20-%2016%3A48%0A2.%20We%20Flood%20Empty%20Lakes%20-%2011%3A44%0A3.%20A%20Song%20for%20Starlit%20Beaches%20-%2019%3A44%0A4.%20Illuminate%20My%20Heart%2C%20My%20Darling%20-%2017%3A31)

### Explanation

```
qN/{      e# Read input and split into lines.
  T60b    e# Push T (initially zero, we use this to keep track of the total time in
          e# seconds), and convert it to base 60.
  Z0e[    e# Pad it with zeroes to 3 digits to get hours, minutes, seconds.
  "(%d:%02d:%02d) "e%
          e# Get the (h:mm:ss) part using a format string.
  \S/     e# Pull up the current line, split on spaces.
  1>      e# Discard the first segment, i.e. the track number.
  )':/    e# Pull off the last segment, i.e. the time, and split on colons.
  60b     e# Interpret the two parts as base-60 digits to get the amount of seconds
          e# for the track.
  T+:T;   e# Add this to T and discard it.
  W<      e# Discard the last segment of the remaining string (the hyphen).
  S*N     e# Join the song name back together with spaces and push a line feed.
}/
```

Comment: goddammit Martin

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, (93 chars plus `-p`) 94 bytes

```pl
s!\d+\. (.+) - (\d+:(\d+))!sprintf"(%d:%02d:%02d) $1",$n/3600,$n%3600/60,$n%60,$n+=$3+60*$2!e
```

To run:

```sh
perl -pe 's!\d+\. (.+) - (\d+:(\d+))!sprintf"(%d:%02d:%02d) $1",$n/3600,$n%3600/60,$n%60,$n+=$3+60*$2!e' <<< '<input>'
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>170</s> 160 Bytes

Been a while since I've done a golf, hopefully this isn't too bad :P

```py
t=0
for i in input().split('\n'):i=i.split(' - ');print'(%d:%02d:%02d)'%(t/3600,t%3600/60,t%60),i[0].split('. ')[1];k=i[-1].split(':');t+=int(k[0])*60+int(k[1])
```

The input should be surrounded by quotes, and split by newlines, like so:

```py
"1. Concerning the UFO Sighting Near Highland Illinois - 2:08\n2. The Black Hawk War - 2:14\n3. Come On Feel the Illinoise - 6:45\n4. John Wayne Gacy Jr - 3:19\n5. Jacksonville - 5:24\n6. A Short Reprise for Mary Todd Who Went Insane but for Very Good Reasons - 0:47\n7. Decatur or Round of Applause for Your Stepmother - 3:03\n8. One Last Whoo Hoo for the Pullman - 0:06\n9. Chicago - 6:04\n10. Casimir Pulaski Day - 5:53\n11. To the Workers of the Rock River Valley Region - 1:40\n12. The Man of Metropolis Steals Our Hearts - 6:17\n13. Prairie Fire That Wanders About - 2:11\n14. A Conjunction of Drones Simulating the Way - 0:19\n15. The Predatory Wasp of the Palisades Is Out to Get Us - 5:23\n16. They Are Night Zombies They Are Neighbors They Have Come Back from the Dead Ahhhh - 5:09\n17. Lets Hear That String Part Again Because I Dont Think They Heard It All the Way Out in Bushnell - 0:40\n18. In This Temple as in the Hearts of Man for Whom He Saved the Earth - 0:35\n19. The Seers Tower - 3:53\n20. The Tallest Man the Broadest Shoulders - 7:02\n21. Riffs and Variations on a Single Note  - 0:46\n22. Out of Egypt into the Great Laugh of Mankind and I Shake the Dirt from My Sandals as I Run - 4:21"
```

Comment: I think you can just have `%d` for the hours counter (if I understand the rules correctly!) for `-2`!

Comment: Add 4 chars (`input` to `raw_input`) to accept the exact format; otherwise I believe it's invalid as it assumes lines in a different format.

Answer (score 5):

## C++, <del>212</del> <del>209</del> <del>202</del> 189 bytes

C++ because.. why not?

```
#include<iostream>
long d,t,u;main(){std::string a,b(8,0);while(getline(std::cin>>t>>a[0],a,'-')>>t>>b[0]>>u){strftime(&b[0],9,"%T",gmtime(&d));b[0]='(';std::cout<<b+")"+a+'\n';d+=t*60+u;}}
```

Live:
<del>[212](https://ideone.com/LHP0ma)</del>
<del>[209](https://ideone.com/I2ihgJ)</del>
<del>[202](https://ideone.com/f2qoF7)</del>
[189](https://ideone.com/3DvV16)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>207</s> 206 bytes

```
h=m=s=0
for i in raw_input().splitlines():
 print("(%d:%.2d:%.2d) "%(h,m,s),i.split('-')[0].split('. ')[1])
 t=i.split('-')[1].split(':')
 m+=int(t[0]);s+=int(t[1]);r=s//60;s-=r*60;m+=r;r=m//60;m-=r*60;h+=r
```

### Usage

```
$ python test.py
'1. Concerning the UFO Sighting Near Highland Illinois - 2:08\n2. The Black Hawk War - 2:14\n3. Come On Feel the Illinoise - 6:45'
(0:00:00) Concerning the UFO Sighting Near Highland Illinois 
(0:02:08) The Black Hawk War 
(0:04:22) Come On Feel the Illinoise
```

Comment: What version of Python 3 are you using? I thought `raw_input` only existed in Python 2.

Comment: Fixed. I guess I'm just used to typing "3". @Mauris

Answer (score 3):

## Gema, 151 characters

```
\B=@set{t;}
<D>. * - <D>\:<D>=(@div{$t;3600}:@fill-right{00;@div{@mod{$t;3600};60}}:@fill-right{00;@mod{$t;60}}) *@set{t;@add{@add{$t;$4};@mul{$3;60}}}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '\B=@set{t;};<D>. * - <D>\:<D>=(@div{$t;3600}:@fill-right{00;@div{@mod{$t;3600};60}}:@fill-right{00;@mod{$t;60}}) *@set{t;@add{@add{$t;$4};@mul{$3;60}}}' tracklist.txt
(0:00:00) Concerning the UFO Sighting Near Highland Illinois
(0:02:08) The Black Hawk War
(0:04:22) Come On Feel the Illinoise
(0:11:07) John Wayne Gacy Jr
(0:14:26) Jacksonville
(0:19:50) A Short Reprise for Mary Todd Who Went Insane but for Very Good Reasons
(0:20:37) Decatur or Round of Applause for Your Stepmother
(0:23:40) One Last Whoo Hoo for the Pullman
(0:23:46) Chicago
(0:29:50) Casimir Pulaski Day
```

Answer (score 1):

## awk, <s>119</s> 101 bytes

```
{split($NF,t,":");$1=$(--NF)="";--NF;print"("substr(strftime("%H:%M:%S",s,1),2)")"$0;s+=t[1]*60+t[2]}
```

<s>This is *way* longer than I wanted it to be. The problem is that `%H` doesn't format the hours like requested, so I needed to calculate the hours myself.</s>

Ack, I'm stupid. The results of `strftime` were wrong because I needed to tell it to use UTC time. That cut 18 bytes off!

### 119-byte version

```
{split($NF,t,":");$1=$(--NF)="";--NF;print"("(h||0)":"strftime("%M:%S",s)")"$0;s=(r=s+t[1]*60+t[2])%3600;h=int(r/3600)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3 (3.8>=)](https://www.python.org), 115 bytes

```py
a=0
while 1:_,*s,_,t=input().split();print(f"({a//3600}:%02d:%02d)"%(a//60%60,a%60),*s);a+=int(t[0])*60+int(t[2:4])
```

Ungolfed version:

```py
a = 0
while True:
    _,*s,_,t = input().split()                         # Skip firt element and the second to last 
    print(f"({a//3600}:%02d:%02d)"%(a//60%60,a%60),*s) # Print time + what is between the number and the -
    a+=int(t[0])*60+int(t[2:4])                        # Increment time
```

Exit with error.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RVTBbttGEL30xK8YBDBgJbJCUhRtM_BBrmNLgWULkmKhLYJgLa7ErahdYrm0IQT9kl58aYF-R_-hQPs1fbOUWwEiwdmZN_PmPfLX36u9K4x-efmtceuTs79rcREGz4UqJUXZ1-7buvu16y6Urhp33OnVValw_1BZpd3x-s3xN_H-fT8Nw1-yozDO_aXz5ugY0TQ8SsOuwKUDlM4H8e6Ca9xP4ZfO2zR81z7EWfKl07Y-TPDyz3d_RT363uiVtFrpDblC0ufre5qrTeE4cCeFpRGeSqFzGpel0kbVdEJxFp4FcY8WqLgsxWpLI_G8pSXS-TBKgj4j7yTda7qWsvTYrwASSWmWDIKkR59MoVG315JuxGpPnxihn0XnwQCHQK6NflJlyTWDLE6CtEdDmhfGOppJrAdoa2NpIuyeFibPaVkYWkrtaKxrAdjHxvmMB4mMG2Ny1AmgMo8wS06D0x5dyZVwjSWkzUwDrmZNw6oqRXOA_8HgdO5ktTNg0s4Y9oOzHghKuhW1476GRvhzPtOdNmW5E9q3CdPgHBsp1EpsjKcfJkEUIiRqtVOWk0W9VXQl9p7poB9EUGdhPNTS2K20NY_FjzODjc_UEwZ5ENjNHpQ2ynCrKEvCIDpIM0F3lEyks6YyJaQDBVHWdA82I4jraj9LdBpEEGxqhbJK0rWyEvUCnKA79x0-GmzRSxsFUcISwDc_N3rluC16XFmjJfDVDkTcq5uWnk3IckaDdqaplblwBlosRV29MpoKTCdyIIx5OkfO0I109Lludcc2Ul-_pyGGu2OH0o9m96hQ8n9YIv5o7CE0Ek-ydeElW3Rtzc43u5Iip2GBnwcPMRw8cCuxDV5KS33uLLOYYkk03Ail6RImYT-M6crAXotC6e2hEarwfiCxLP_jzSy4qqkLLRH3boM28MxYczWmlLsKzhY1J3LdQRPWDNKxkeCqHcI0B5fc53xESuHR-oMgOm-3Opcs08I8H7wJ-8Rhe7Rgh8CfjMj1l9bwoh2_RE3p5T2h0yyMgxiGm6n1uiZ-3R-EVYLlxTyaBKTVGwx7Z5xsuaRBDJ8xTcz7cbOvmK9rDXtjJXZ4K5pNcWCzVcD0nxE0FlvZKqGwXa_LZA-KOmdzYh1jmjXs5iSLoyD21vzzj7LJZZfuq158lmGMXpT6_dIahqMJvizW-z_st9-3fwE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>112</s> 109 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Steffan*

```rb
a=0
loop{_,*s,_,t=gets.split;puts "(%d:%02d:%02d) "%[a/3600,a/60%60,a%60]+s*' ';a+=t[0].to_i*60+t[2..4].to_i}
```

Exit with error

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RVTLbuNGELzkxK9oLGBsYstcknrY1sIHOVpbWli2IGktJMbCGIkjcSJyhhgOvRCC_ZK9-JAc8h35hwDJ16R6KCcCJIE93dVdXTX89putV_uXl99rtzk9_7sQl1GQG1P--tQ6rlpPLXe5la4KqzJX7n1Zu4refH-U9o-ipPn5gd4cPYp37V4UtcS7XnTUwz9-Pp9Ux2_p7Xtxcukeo8-hM0_quBeduMckDDvN89em6aH3yz_f_RWH9KPRa2m10ltymaRP1_c0V9vMceBOCksjPOVCpzTOc6WNquiUkn50HiQhLVBxlYv1jkbiy46WSOfDuBO0GbmQdK_pWsrcY78CSCT1-p1u0Anpo8k06vZa0o1Y7-kjI7T78UXQxSGQK6OfVZ5zTbefdIJeSAOaZ8Y6msnSMtrGWJoIu6eFSVNaZoaWUjsa60oAdlU7n_EgkXFjTIo6AVTmEfU7Z8FZSEO5Fq62hLSZqcHVbGhQlrmoD_A_GZzOnSwLAybNjFE7OA9BUNKtqBz3NTTCl_OZ7rTO80Jo3ybqBRfYSKbWYms8_agTxBFColKFspwsqp2iodh7pt12EEOdhfFQS2N30lY8Fj_ODDY-U88Y5EFgN3tQ2irDreJ-JwrigzQTdEfJRDprSpNDOlAQeUX3YDOCuK7ys8RnQQzBplYoqyRdKytRL8AJunPfwcpgi17aOIg7LAF880ut147bosfQGi2BrwoQca9uWno2EcsZd5uZplamwhlosRRV-cpoKjCdSIEw5ukcOUM30tGnqtEd2-j5-j0NMNwdO5R-NsVKoeT_sER8ZewhNBLPsnHhFVt0Y03hmw2lSGmQ4ePBIwwHD9zi3vmlNNTnzjKLKZZEg61Qmq5gEvbDmIYG9lpkSu8OjVCF-4HEPP-PN7PgqrrKtETcuw3awDNjzdWYUhYlnC0qTuS6gyasGaRjI8FVBcI0B5fU53xASubR2t0gvmi2Opcs08J8OXgT9kmi5mjBDoE_GZHrr6zhRTu-RHXu5T2ls36UBAkMN1ObTUV83R-EVYLlxTyaBKTVWwx7Z5xsuPSCBD5jmpj3w3ZfMl_XGPbGSuzwVtTb7MBmp4DpXyNoLHayUUJhu16XyR4UdcrmxDrGNKvZzZ1-EgeJt-aff-R1Klt0X4bJeR9jhHHP75c2MBxN8Gax3v9Ru3m__Qs)

Comment: `(...)while 1` => `loop{...}`